# comparison between the admission of a degree in two countries

Tags: discussion, on-topic-ness, asking-questions, allowed-questions

Is it really off-topic to ask a comparison between the admission process of a degree in two countries ?

Comment: Are you referring to [non-US PhD's with extensive course work](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/63859/non-us-phds-with-extensive-course-work)? I have to admit, I cannot understand what you're asking there, so I can't really say whether it's on topic.  "What are my best options" is [not really an answerable question](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/questions/1203/welcome-to-academia-se/1205#1205).

Comment: Regardless, I *definitely* don't see how you're asking for a comparison of the admissions process of US vs Europe from that question. The post doesn't seem to ask anything about admissions processes. If that's really what you were trying to ask, you should edit that post to clarify.

Comment: Admission processes might vary a lot also from university to university within the same country.

Comment: @ff524 i was not exactly referring to that qstion. The exact admission processes may vary in each university, but there can be common rules or procedures for different countries or regions.

Answer (score 3):

A general comparison between admission processes in two countries might or might not be on-topic, depending on the nature of the question.

For example, we have a [question on the general process of admissions in the US](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/38237/22733).  A question on how to compare the admission processes of specific universities (e.g., UT Austin vs. TU Delft) would definitely be off-topic, as discussion of the unique policies of specific universities is generally off-topic on this site.

From your question, though, I am actually quite unclear what you are attempting to ask, however, so I am not sure how to suggest you refine it to be answerable.